# Spring @initBinder method to be called only once inside a controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, propertyeditor, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have a class that annotated with `@RestController` and `@ControllerAdvice` that has my requests mapped methods (`@RequestMapping`). Also in this class I added a method `public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder)` that is annotated with `@InitBinder` and responsible to register some custom editor.
Specifically, it is a `propertyEditor` that convert String to Enum.

I noticed that on every call to `@RequestMapping` method in my controller, my initBinder method is being called. Since in my opinion this editor registration should happen only once (initialization of controller), I want this to be set (called) only once.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use implementation of BindingInitializer for registering your custom Editor. You have to define a bean of class "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" in your app context file and set its "webBindingInitializer" property with your implementation of BindingInitializer.

In any case, scope of  WebDataBinder is for a request. Hope this helps.

Comment: AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter is deprecated. as of Spring 3.2, in favor of RequestMappingHandlerAdapter